# Keep Desktop from showing inside the Workspace Indicator

Tags: gnome, workspaces

how do i exclude the desktop from being shown in the workspace indicator, it shows on all 4. the desktop comes from the default gnome extension DING.

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

[image: workspace indicator]